# vim. интеллектуальное переименование

Tags: vim, scope, рефакторинг, область-видимости

В некоторых популярных IDE есть функция `рефакторинг->переименование переменной` (или что-то подобное), которая позволяет переименовать переменную во всех местах использования, при этом учитывается область видимости этой переменной: одноименные переменные в других областях видимости не будут переименовываться. Это свойство я и имел в виду, озаглавив вопрос "интеллектуальное переименование".

А можно ли сделать что-то такое в vim?

Проиллюстрирую:

из

```
void foo()
{
  int a = 0; // нужно переименовать эту
  ...
  if(someCondition)
  {
    int a = 1;
    bar(a);
  }
  ...
  bar(a);
}
```

хочется получить

```
void foo()
{
  int someName = 0;
  ...
  if(someCondition)
  {
    int a = 1;
    bar(a);
  }
  ...
  bar(someName);
}
```

при помощи vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, переименование с учётом вложенных областей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание действий:

1. Переходим на блок, в котором переименовывать ничего не нужно.
2. Скрываем его, нажав `zc`.
3. Выполняем переименовывание в остальной части текста:

   `:foldd s/\<a\>/название_со_смыслом/g`
4. Раскрываем скрытый блок нажав `zr`.

Comment: шикарно! Правда, интеллектуальность всё еще в основном остаётся за пользователем.

Answer (score 1):

Для переименования переменных, расположенных во вложенных областях видимости, достаточным решением можно считать ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597687/changing-variable-names-in-vim)):

```
Переместить курсор на переменную
gd - для перемещению к определению переменной в текущей области видимости
[{ - для перехода к началу области видимости
V - для перехода в визуальный режим
% - для перехода к закрывающей скобке }
:s/oldName/newName/g - выполните команду для замены строки в указанной области.
```

Также работают следующие варианты:

```
:xx,yys/oldName/newName/g
```

где xx, yy - номер начальной и конечной строки соответственно,
или

```
:'a'bs/oldName/newName/g
```

где a, b - закладки (mark).

Но к сожалению, это далеко от интеллектуального переименования и в случае наличия вложенных областей видимости будет переименовывать одноименные переменные в них.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос уже [задавался](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781975/refactoring-in-vim) на англоязычном StackOverflow. Также возможно Вам поможет [эта статья](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_as_a_refactoring_tool_and_some_examples_in_C_sharp) на Vim Wiki.

Плагины, поддерживающие рефакторинг:

- [vim-refactor](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-refactor) - C, C++, Java, Pascal, VimL
- [vim-ruby-refactoring](https://github.com/ecomba/vim-ruby-refactoring) - Ruby
- [ropevim](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim) - Python
- [vim-php-refactoring-toolbox](https://github.com/adoy/vim-php-refactoring-toolbox) - PHP
- [vim-hare](https://github.com/glittershark/vim-hare) - Haskell
- [omnisharp-vim](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim) - C#

Comment: Хорошая подборка плагинов, однако вопрос касался именно случая перекрытия имен переменных в разных областях видимости и переименования в этом случае, а не инструментов рефакторинга в целом.

Comment: @LXA перечисленные плагины умеют переименовывать переменные с учётом областей видимости, но этим не ограничиваются, да