# Как переименовывать переменную глобально в vim?

Tags: vim

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512732/vim-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) поднимается вопрос, но ответ дает решение лишь на уровне файла. Как переименовывать переменную глобально, сразу во всех файлах, в которых она используется (как это можно сделать во многих IDE)? Если это делается с помощью плагина, то нужно, чтобы была поддержка Java

[Этот плагин у меня не работает](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-refactor)

Comment: Та причина по которой пришлось перейти на vscode: я хочу программировать, а не настраивать редактор